# Get notification's email from issue

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

There is any way to know by code the email associated to the Notification given a issue?

[image]

I tried

```
ComponentAccessor.getNotificationSchemeManager().getNotificationSchemeForProject(issue.getProject())
```

This gives me the Notification Scheme (`COGP_NPS_SERVICEDESK`) but I cannot find any property there that give me the email (`xxxx@gmail.com` in my example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

```
issue.getProjectObject().getEmail()
```